# "dashdotted" command not working for tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex, updating

I am trying to create pictures of graphs in TikZ in which I'd like some edges to be `dashdotted`. I am using TeXShop on both my office computer (Mac) and my personal laptop (Mac), and the file is compiling fine on my office computer but when I try to compile the same file on my laptop, I am getting the following error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dashdotted' and
I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it...
```

I reinstalled the latest version of MacTex on my laptop to see if this fixed the problem, but it has not.

Here is the code I have in my test document which will not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashdotted] (0,0)--(10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version of PGF/TikZ do you have on your Laptop? Check with `\pgfversion`.

Comment: I have 2.00-cvs.

Comment: On the office computer I have version 2.10, if that helps.

Comment: That’s an old CVS version. I guess you installed that manually a long time ago in a local texmf tree. Delete it and compile your document again. Maybe you need to update PGF/TikZ then, too. Either way, the current version is 2.10.

Comment: Great. How would I locate that old version to delete it?

Comment: 1. Check all folders your TeX distribution uses. 2. Use the utilities of your OS to find files and folders with `pgf` in it. 3. Check the `.log` file, all files loaded are listed there. `pgf` has to come up at some point.

Comment: I have found the pgf files using the terminal, but I'm not sure which one(s) to delete and how to delete them. All are located in 

/usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/tex/latex/local/tex/latex/pgf

and the files are frontendlayer/tikz.sty, basiclayer/pgf.sty, and utilities/pgfrcs.sty

I also just ran a complete update of the pgf packages using the TeX Live Utility, and \pgfversion is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, that does not surprise me. The files are in `texmf-local`, the updater does not replace them but the ones in the main texmf tree (where ever that is on a Mac). It should suffice to delete the `/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/tex/latex/pgf` folder.

Comment: In the /textmf-local/tex/latex/local/tex/latex directory I wrote into the terminal rm -rf pgf and was denied permission, so I am not sure how to delete it.

I apologize for the long discussion, but I cannot move the discussion to the chat since I don't have the reputation.

Comment: @AlysonB Type `sudo rm -rf pgf` and the terminal will require an administrator password; if you're the owner of the machine your usual password will suffice.

Comment: Thanks. That did work and the pgf folder is gone, however it does not solve the problem. The log file still says \pgfversion is 2.00-cvs. There are also pgf folders in /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/tex/latex/local/tex/generic/ and /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex. Should I be deleting these as well?

Comment: I know this is closed, but I just wanted to say... I figured it out! I had to delete all my local installed files, which were overriding the current version. Yay! Thanks for your help, @Qrrbrbirlbel and egreg